# Why do we say "run apps" and not "walk" them?

Tags: etymology

I was recently working on an application and it was showing its status as "Running", and this thought popped up in my head: why "run" and not "walk"?

What's the origin of this difference?

Tried to search but couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: Computers are fast.

Comment: In the Scandinavian languages, they _drive_…

Comment: In other languages, they sometimes *march*.